# How to move files to a folder within a library using workflow?

Tags: document, library, move

I have a situation like this. I have an asset library and I want to use a workflow so that, every time a user upload a file, it is automatically moved to a folder by the file type (extension).

For example, I now have a `.png` image and I want the workflow to recognize the file type and move it to a folder named **Pictures**.

[image: The workflow I created]

As you can see, I've tried to the point of setting the `to` part with the hard link to my folder and end with the `/_vti_bin/officialfile.asmx` suffix. And yet, the workflow couldn't run.

Any idea why?

I'm currently running Sharepoint 2013.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

there is an existing post which i tried and worked fine. you can also use the same logic by additionally checking the file type.

[Reference Link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112331/use-workflow-to-move-document-within-document-library-to-different-folder-in-sam/112338#comment150308_112338)