# Workflow Can't Find Path and Name

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-foundation

I need help creating a workflow in Sharepoint Designer 2013 (on Sharepoint 2010 Foundation).

Essentially what happens is, users will create an item on a list and attach a file.  Well, I need a workflow that then scoops up that file, and moves it to a specific document library.

I've found multiple articles out there that say you need to `Update item in this list`, then set the `Path and Name` field to be the new location.

Problem is, when I click on `this list` and then click Add in the Update List Item dialogue box, I don't see `Path and Name` as an available field to update.  I see `Attachments`, but that just appears to be a boolean that signifies whether the item has an attachment.

Am I looking in the wrong place to set the `Path and Name` variable?  Is that not available on whatever SP component I have running that this may rely on?

Here is an example of something I read that tells me to update the `Path and Name` field:
[Use workflow to move document within document library to different folder in same library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112331/use-workflow-to-move-document-within-document-library-to-different-folder-in-sam)

And, here is a screenshot of SharePoint designer *not* giving me the option to update said field:

[image]

Another thing I don't understand is... if you update the path "field" of a file in the database, how does that actually move the file from one physical location on the file server to another?  Is there SharePoint sorcery that knows that the `Path and Name` has been updated, and just magically knows to physically relocate the file?

Comment: can you explain clearly with screen shots and links that you visited.

Comment: It's actually quite simple. If you add an attachment to an item in a list, I want a workflow to automatically move that attachment somewhere else. That's the goal. I've found 3 articles that have told me to have the workflow alter the Path and Name field (those articles can be easily found if you just search for them), but when I try to "Update item in this list," I don't get the option to update a Path and Name field.

Comment: I got your point. But I'm not sure that actually you can seperate(seggregate) attachment from list item. There are two cases that you can do this process. case1: you can copy the whole list item to the new list.so that attachment also will be linked to item. case2: Ignore the list attachment and you can create a document library and send the document to other (Document library/Folder)location which is very possible solution. Let us see some one can guide you to go with the list and to copy the attachment. If you are fine with document library, your job will be quite easy :) that's it

Answer (score 0):

This might be long moot - but I think your original List is a list (why it has an attachment). You can't put folders in plain old lists. You would have to have a second library to use.

So, you'd say "Create List Item" (rather than update item in current list) then select the Library where you want the folder to be created. If it is actually a Library, I think it will offer you a folder content type. You could also go and add custom content types and include folders... but I don't know the consequences of doing that in a list.

I'm not sure about the 2nd part - the scooping up of the attachment, but maybe you could copy it or move it. But I don't see that when I look up options in my Designer 2013.

PS - sorry this isn't a comment. It says I can't do that until I have a 50 reputation.